# Elemen-wise multiplication of numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

Multiplying elements of numpy arrays based on elements in one array.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(-10,10, size=(12, 4))
x = np.insert(arr=x, values=np.random.choice([1,2,3,4], 12), obj=8, axis=1)
```

How can I multiply rows of x[:,:4] element-wise provided that these rows have identical element in the last column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for grouping your rows based on 4th element then use [`np.multiply`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) within [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function to calculate the `multiply`
:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y:np.multiply(x,y),g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(x,key=itemgetter(3)),itemgetter(3))]
[array([ 0, -7, -5, -7]), array([   0, -588, 1296,    1]), array([ 9, -3, -1,  0]), array([ 56,  -8, -60,   9]), array([ -9,  -3, -10,   6]), array([-72,  -9, -15,  64]), array([ 5, -8, -5,  9])]
```